# in Battlegrounds, do minions from players that just died go back to the 'pool'?

Tags: hearthstone

in Battlegrounds, you select minions from a pool that you share with other players.  when you sell your minions, they go back to the shared pool.  What about when a player die, do the minions that they had in play go back in the pool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minions do go back into the pool if they sell the minion or die.

[This guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/CompetitiveHS/comments/dujmak/hearthstone_battlegrounds_basics_you_should_know/) has a good write up.

Specifically [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/BobsTavern/comments/dst4tz/questions_about_battleground_rules/f6wc5r8/) in the article.